# How to retrieve web application root path in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am coding my Spring MVC based web application (which was deployed with a **war** file) and trying to get the value of

`String rootDir = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");`

I am expecting to get

```
"C:\user\projects\MyApp"
```

but the actual value is

```
"C:\user\projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyApp\"
```

I tried to change **Source Folder Output Location** in Eclipse, but after that all my jsp files, web.xml and folder \WEB-INF are gone. How can I restore them?

The reason I am asking this is that I want my uploaded images to be saved in **"MyApp\webapp\WEB-INF\resources\images\"** folder.

Comment: Define why you want to have that path? Is there some specific need or you are doing it for uploading image?

Comment: As Issam EL ATIF said this thing is quite impossible but what you can do is upload to separate folder i.e. anywhere in file system and when next time when you restart your server before that copy past that folder to your `WEB-INF` Or set up temporarily ftp this will be the best option you can go for as this will not need you to do any copy past and will also retrieve the file or image back to your page as soon as you finish uploading it in real-time. if you go for ftp it will also be easier for you to deal with this situation when you actually put your site to production or make it live.

Comment: Use this spring boot guide : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: Google how resource files are defined in Spring. Otherwise these resource folders will disappear when you compile and pack your app into war. You should not use absolute paths in order to keep your app portable. You deploy your app on server, not in eclipse workspace. Moreover resource folders are for resources. It's a good practise to store files in server folders outside your project. Of course it's your own choice. Here's one [example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you expecting the path to be `"C:\user\projects\MyApp"`?

Your are running your application using Eclipse and Eclipse is deploying it to `C:\user\projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core` and not running it from project source folder that is why you get `"C:\user\projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyApp\"` from getRealPath() call.

From `ServletContext#getRealPath()`

> **Gets the real path corresponding to the given virtual path. For
>   example, if path is equal to /index.html, this method will return the
>   absolute file path on the server's filesystem to which a request of
>   the form http://://index.html would be
>   mapped, where  corresponds to the context path of this
>   ServletContext.**
>
> **The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer
>   and operating system on which the servlet container is running,
>   including the proper path separators.**
>
> Resources inside the /META-INF/resources directories of JAR files
>   bundled in the application's /WEB-INF/lib directory must be considered
>   only if the container has unpacked them from their containing JAR
>   file, in which case the path to the unpacked location must be
>   returned.
>
> This method returns null if the servlet container is unable to
>   translate the given virtual path to a real path.

Comment: I expect to get the path as "C:\user\projects\MyApp" just because I want then my uploaded images to be stored in the folder "MyApp\webapp\WEB-INF\resources\images".